# NSMetadataQuery not working

Tags: ios, icloud, nsmetadataquery

I am trying to use iCloud in my app. In the simulator, I notice that it takes a short amount of time after launch for new files in iCloud to be added to the ubiquity container. So to refresh my UI to reflect these changes, I set up an NSMetadataQuery as shown:

```
_query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
_query.searchScopes = @[ubiquityContainer];
_query.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == '*'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshFiles) name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification object:nil];
[_query startQuery];
```

`refreshFiles` is never called...

My app saves its files directly in `ubiquityContainer` (an `NSURL`) - it doesn't create any subdirectories...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `query` a local variable or an instance variable? If it's a local then the problem is that `query` will be deallocated when it goes out of scope.

Comment: But you are aren't using the property, you appear to be directly using the ivar. How is the property declared? Show the `@property` line.

Comment: "@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMetadataQuery *query;" I also use "@synthesize"

Comment: I've now changed it to an ivar, but that doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: Try changing the predicate to `%K like '*'`. You need to use `like` with wildcards.

Comment: I tried, and it still doesn't work. But thanks for your help

Comment: The query doesn't even work locally

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was! I needed to use `NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDataScope` as the search scope. That fixed the problem!